# python scraping - How can I Loop between Dates in OddsPortal

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape Oddsportal and the below code however when I run it, I get `IndexError`

Code:

```
import threading
from datetime import datetime
from math import nan
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver



class Driver:
    def __init__(self):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        # Un-comment next line to supress logging:
        options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    def __del__(self):
        self.driver.quit()  # clean up driver when we are cleaned up
        # print('The driver has been "quitted".')


threadLocal = threading.local()


def create_driver():
    the_driver = getattr(threadLocal, 'the_driver', None)
    if the_driver is None:
        the_driver = Driver()
        setattr(threadLocal, 'the_driver', the_driver)
    return the_driver.driver


class GameData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.date = []
        self.time = []
        self.game = []
        self.score = []
        self.home_odds = []
        self.draw_odds = []
        self.away_odds = []
        self.country = []
        self.league = []


def generate_matches(pgSoup, defaultVal=None):
    evtSel = {
        'time': 'p.whitespace-nowrap',
        'game': 'a div:has(>a[title])',
        'score': 'a:has(a[title])+div.hidden',
        'home_odds': 'a:has(a[title])~div:not(.hidden)',
        'draw_odds': 'a:has(a[title])~div:not(.hidden)+div:nth-last-of-type(3)',
        'away_odds': 'a:has(a[title])~div:nth-last-of-type(2)',
    }

    events, current_group = [], {}
    for evt in pgSoup.select('div[set]>div:last-child'):
        if evt.parent.select(f':scope>div:first-child+div+div'):
            cgVals = [v.get_text(' ').strip() if v else defaultVal for v in [
                evt.parent.select_one(s) for s in
                [':scope>div:first-child+div>div:first-child',
                 ':scope>div:first-child>a:nth-of-type(2):nth-last-of-type(2)',
                 ':scope>div:first-child>a:nth-of-type(3):last-of-type']]]
            current_group = dict(zip(['date', 'country', 'league'], cgVals))

        evtRow = {'date': current_group.get('date', defaultVal)}
        for k, v in evtSel.items():
            v = evt.select_one(v).get_text(' ') if evt.select_one(v) else defaultVal
            evtRow[k] = ' '.join(v.split()) if isinstance(v, str) else v
        evtRow['country'] = current_group.get('country', defaultVal)
        evtRow['league'] = current_group.get('league', defaultVal)

        events.append(evtRow)
    return events


def parse_data(url, return_urls=False):
    browser = create_driver()
    browser.get(url)
    browser.implicitly_wait(25)
    soup = bs(browser.page_source, "lxml")

    game_data = GameData()
    game_keys = [a for a, av in game_data.__dict__.items() if isinstance(av, list)]
    for row in generate_matches(soup, defaultVal=nan):
        for k in game_keys: getattr(game_data, k).append(row.get(k, nan))
    if return_urls:
        span = soup.find('span', {'class': 'next-games-date'})
        a_tags = soup.select('span.next-games-date a[href]') # Instead of a_tags = soup.select('span.next-games-date a[href]')
        urls = ['https://www.oddsportal.com' + a_tag['href'] for a_tag in a_tags]
        return game_data, urls
    return game_data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    games = None
    pool = ThreadPool(5)  # We will be getting, however, 7 URLs
    # Get today's data and the Urls for the other days:
    game_data_today, urls = pool.apply(parse_data, args=('https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer', True))
    urls.pop(1)  # Remove url for today: We already have the data for that
    game_data_results = pool.imap(parse_data, urls)
    for i in range(8):
        try:
            game_data = game_data_today if i == 1 else next(game_data_results)
            result = pd.DataFrame(game_data.__dict__)
            if games is None:
                games = result
            else:
                games = games.append(result, ignore_index=True)
        except ValueError:
            game_data = game_data_today if i == 1 else next(game_data_results)
            result = pd.DataFrame(game_data.__dict__)
            if games is None:
                games = result
            else:
                games = games.append(result, ignore_index=True)
        finally:
            pass
    # print(games)
    # ensure all the drivers are "quitted":
    del threadLocal
    import gc

    gc.collect()  # a little extra insurance
```

Error:

```
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2022.1\scratches\scratch_1.py", line 114, in <module>
    urls.pop(1)  # Remove url for today: We already have the data for that
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

While the looping is to scrape between dates available, I am unable to get it to work in entirety.

[image: Loop Between Dates]

I dont want to check for `a_tags = [] if span is None else span.find_all('a')` as it does not serve my purpose

This part of the code:

```
def generate_matches(pgSoup, defaultVal=None):
    evtSel = {
        'time': 'p.whitespace-nowrap',
        'game': 'a div:has(>a[title])', 
        'score': 'a:has(a[title])+div.hidden', 
        'home_odds': 'a:has(a[title])~div:not(.hidden)',
        'draw_odds': 'a:has(a[title])~div:not(.hidden)+div:nth-last-of-type(3)',
        'away_odds': 'a:has(a[title])~div:nth-last-of-type(2)', 
    }

    events, current_group = [], {}
    for evt in pgSoup.select('div[set]>div:last-child'):
        if evt.parent.select(f':scope>div:first-child+div+div'):
            cgVals = [v.get_text(' ').strip() if v else defaultVal for v in [
              evt.parent.select_one(s) for s in 
              [ ':scope>div:first-child+div>div:first-child',
                ':scope>div:first-child>a:nth-of-type(2):nth-last-of-type(2)',
                ':scope>div:first-child>a:nth-of-type(3):last-of-type' ]]]
            current_group = dict(zip(['date', 'country', 'league'], cgVals))
        
        evtRow = {'date': current_group.get('date', defaultVal)}
        for k, v in evtSel.items():
            v = evt.select_one(v).get_text(' ') if evt.select_one(v) else defaultVal
            evtRow[k] = ' '.join(v.split()) if isinstance(v, str) else v
        evtRow['country'] = current_group.get('country', defaultVal)
        evtRow['league'] = current_group.get('league', defaultVal)

        events.append(evtRow)
    return events
```

collects

[image: pandas.DataFrame(events)]

Edit: Changed `a_tags = soup.select('span.next-games-date a[href]')` to `a_tags = soup.select('span.next-games-date a[href]')`

Comment: Just a note: if there's a chance of the list not having the index you're about to `pop` from, do something like `if len(urls)>1: urls.pop(1)`; you can print a warning in `else:..` so that you'll know there's something missing, but at least you won't lose the data gathered until then due to the program crashing. Ofc, your actual issue is probably that the list is empty at all - hopefully, my answer resolves that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```py
>         span = soup.find('span', {'class': 'next-games-date'})
>         a_tags = span.findAll('a')
> ```

> ```py
>     a_tags = span.findAll('a')
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'
> ```

<sub>You can avoid raising the error by just checking for `None` like **`a_tags = [] if span is None else span.findAll('a')`** [this is something you should do habitually when with `.find`/`.select_one` btw], but you will always get an empty list, due to the reasons explained below.</sub>

**Why** are you using `.find('span', {'class': 'next-games-date'})` when [as evident in the last screenshot in your q] the links are not contained in a `span` tag, and [as far as I could see from inspecting] there are no elements at all with the `next-games-date` class?? Considering this, it should not be surprising that `.find...` returned `None` and the next line raised the error.

---

Given that the screenshot of the inspect tab shows that one of the ancestor is a `div` with a `tabs` class, and that all the `a` tags have an `h-8` class, you could use something like

```py
    if return_urls:
        a_cont = soup.find('div', {'class': 'tabs'})
        if a_cont is None: a_tags = [] # check for None to be safe
        else: a_tags =  a_cont.find_all('a', {'class':'h-8', 'href':True}) 
        urls = [
            'https://www.oddsportal.com'+a_tag['href'] for a_tag in a_tags
            if not a_tag['href'].startswith('#') # sections in current page 
            and 'active-item-calendar' not in a_tag['class'] # current page
        ]
```

or, with `.select`:

```py
    if return_urls:
        a_sel = 'div.tabs a.h-8:not([href^="#"]):not(.active-item-calendar)'
        urls = ['https://www.oddsportal.com'+a['href'] 
                for a in soup.select(a_sel)]
```

[Since you've already filtered out current page (which should be that day's) with *`'active-item-calendar' not in a_tag['class']`* or *`:not(.active-item-calendar)`*, there will be no need to `pop` any items...]

Comment: The code works beautifully now Thank you for helping me understand scraping which is a lot more than I had before. However, can I please request a bit of change in the way the columns `date` and `game` are extracted? Date should be the title of the page while Game should be the teams without the score. [Please find the explanation for the desired values here](https://imgur.com/a/sT0JF8y)

Comment: Where would I add     `h1 = soup.find('h1').text
    m = re.search(r'\d+ \w+ \d{4}$', h1)
    game_date = m[0]` for `date` ? I dont know how I would go about getting the `game` col correctly though

Comment: @Rander since I feel like this is more relevant to your previous q about scraping this site, I've edited my definition of `generate_matches` there. The date is simple [and I just split by `,` since it felt simpler but if regex works betterr go with that], but the scores are coming from the `div...hidden` adjacent to each team name, so you have to get the teams separately and then join them if you want the `game` column without it.

Answer (score 1):

The Traceback literally says where and why your code is erroring out. In the parse_data fnc, `soup.find('span', {'class': 'next-games-date'})` failed to find given class. As per [the BeautifulSoup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find), "If find() can’t find anything, it returns None:", thus `span` is assigned NoneType obj. When the the following line-- `a_tags = span.findAll('a')`--is ran, an AtrributeError occurs because NoneType objects don't have a `findAll` method.

There are 2 additional mistakes with code:
1.) it should be `span.find_all('a)` not `span.findAll('a')` 
2.) There is no class attribute next-games-date (at least not that I could find) on the website.

For some reason the select method is not finding the `div` with class `.flex gap-2 py-3 overflow-x-auto text-xs no-scrollbar`, but I was able to find it with the `find` method and make a list of urls. Heres the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

def get_page_source(url):
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get(url)
        sleep(3)
        return driver.page_source
    finally: driver.quit()

def grab_button_urls(html, tag, attr):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    a_tags = soup.find(tag, attr)\
        .find_all('a')
    return [f"https://www.oddsportal.com{tag['href']}" for tag in a_tags]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    website = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer'
    # get page source
    pg_html = get_page_source(website)
    # get urls from date buttons
    tag, class_attr = 'div', {'class':'flex gap-2 py-3 overflow-x-auto text-xs no-scrollbar'}
    tags = grab_button_urls(pg_html, tag, class_attr)
    print(tags)
```

Comment: You are correct. How can I correct that part of the code so that I get the code working again? [I am looking at this link](https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer)

Comment: Thank you! I changed the part from `find_all` to `soup.select`. Got a new error that I dont know how to resolve lol

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: `urls.pop(1)  # Remove url for today: We already have the data for that
IndexError: pop from empty list` Updated the code in the question

Comment: Are you trying to collect all href values from the Yesterday, Today, ..., 07 Feb buttons?

Comment: Yes.. Not just values but also the URLs as the dataframe loop will be cycling between those URLs

Comment: pass `'.flex gap-2 py-3 overflow-x-auto text-xs no-scrollbar a'` to the `select` method. That should return a list of all the child `a` tags of the `div` with `class='flex gap-2 py-3 overflow-x-auto text-xs no-scrollbar'`.

Comment: Thank you, Where exactly in the code should I pass this?

Comment: I tried `a_tags = soup.select('.flex gap-2 py-3 overflow-x-auto text-xs no-scrollbar a')` as advised but I still get the same error `urls.pop(1)  # Remove url for today: We already have the data for that
IndexError: pop from empty list` . Not sure if I am doing it the correct way as intended.

Comment: @Übermensch [about *"For some reason the `select` method is not finding the `div` with class ... but I was able to find it with the `find` "*] CSS selectors need a `.` before *every* class, so `div.flex.gap-2.py-3.overflow-x-auto.text-xs.no-scrollbar` [or maybe even `div[class="flex gap-2 py-3 overflow-x-auto text-xs no-scrollbar"]`] would probably have worked

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the example in the BeautifulSoup documentation. I appreciate you taking the time to let me know.